# VPN IKE over TCP

Tags: 12.04, vpn

I need a VPN connection to my work.
It seems that the problem is the checkpoint client which is used in the Windows landscape.
Is there any possibility that I can build such a connection under Ubuntu 12.04?
Your help is much appreciated.

br
snofla

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! What did you try so far and what exactly is not working? Please specify your questions and add more details describing your problem!

Comment: I did not try anything yet because I don't know which client / setup I can use to get that VPN running.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes preinstalled with VPN support. This features is available under the networks connections tab:

- Make sure `network-manager` is installed (should be on any default Ubuntu distribution).
- Open `System > Preferences > Network Connections` or click the network-manager tray icon and select `VPN-Connections > Configure VPN ...`
- Click the `+ Add` button and enter the VPN details of your work account.

Comment: Yes, but where can I choice the IKE over TCP, as far as I can see is only pptp available